# jQuery -change from class to custom attribute

Tags: jquery

I an trying to change a plug in from being based on anchor classes to being based on a custom attribute.

so from: a.categoryname

to: a data-category="categoryname"

The plug in I am customising is:
http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/create-an-automatic-content-filter-using-jquery-css-classes/

I won't post all the code here as I am almost there but but am having a problem with this line:

```
$("#demo-list li a."+getText).fadeIn();
```

instead of fading in #demo-list li a."getText), I want it to fade in #demo-list li a, whose attribute "category-name" is "getText"

Here is my horrendous attempt...

```
$("#demo-list li a).attr("data-category").val(getText).fadeIn();
```

Needless to say it doesn't work... I know enough to know the syntax is not right but not enough to fix it...

Can anyone help me out here please?

thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you changing it to use `data-`?  Also, are these always `data-` attributes, or can they ever be set using jQuery's `.data`?

Comment: The reason I wanted to change them is that I come at this from a design perspective and I like to keep classes for styling and attributes for data. Not sure whether that's the correct way to approach it or not but it seems to be more "semantic" to me that way. I am not sure about using jQuery's .data ... the idea here is to set the data-category attribute via php. One down side of using the attribute as opposed to classes is that while an anchor could have multiple categories as classes, it can only have one as an attribute - but that works OK in this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
$("#demo-list li a[data-category='" + getText + "']").fadeIn();
```

What this does is use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to select the `a` element whose attribute `data-category` equals the value of `getText`.

Answer (score 1):

To search by attribute you can use square brackets:

```
$("#demo-list li [data-category='"+getText+"']").fadeIn();
```

Docs for attribute selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that, it is only a quote missing?

```
$("#demo-list li a").attr("data-category").val(getText).fadeIn();
```